# Can't connect to wamp server from android app

Tags: android, wamp, android-virtual-device

I know my php file works, I can call it from localhost and I get the response.
I also know I have the correct ip address for calling it from the AVD because when I call the url from the browser in the AVD I get a response.
So the problem is in my asynctask function.

Here's my code from the asynctask class.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String str) {
    // updating UI from Background Thread
    resp=str;
    returned();
}
```

I'm calling this class from the parent class and putting the string from onpostexecute() to string resp, which is a string in the parent class.  The response is always null.

Comment: your method doinbackground return null. instead , you should check these questions : did your wamp server is online ?? right click ( put Online) ?if it is , the address of localhost in android is 10.0.2.2 and not localhot or 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you ARE returning `null`, so your code is working as written.

Maybe instead of `return null` in `doInBackground()`, you want to return part of the http response?